# I am looking for a daily report template for programming jobs

Tags: phd, job, working-time

I am a PhD student of computer science. I want to find a good template file that I can report my daily works to the professor and show him what a regular and hard working person I am! I also like to make a work track (I don't know what to call it) that I can refer to while a problem happened in the future or any other reasons.

Do you have any template, experience or idea about what I am talking about?

Comment: Did your professor ask you for this? Having this kind of notekeeping can actually be very good for *you*. Having a record of everything you have done will help you write up results later, can help you prepare for research meetings, and can help you figure out what the next steps should be when you get stuck. But, most advisors I have met would probably not want to read daily updates over an extended period of time. They will see you are hardworking by your progress in meetings, by paper drafts you write, conversations you have, etc.

Comment: For what it is worth, I've used OneNote to keep a log of things I do, it works well for me (but is far from the only option).

Comment: @Andrew: No he didn't. But for myself I want to do it. Also I had a problem with my previous professor and he wrote a bad report against me while I was doing very well. So I came up this idea to collect my daily works also for the future judgement. Also I am looking for another benefits that you mentioned in your comment too,

Answer (score 4):

I generally wouldn't recommend sending daily updates to your advisor unless they ask you to. Because professors can get literally hundreds or even thousands of emails in a day, expecting them to read this report could be perceived as annoying and unnecessary, especially if you have regular research meetings to discuss progress.

However, developing a good system to take notes *is* a very good idea. There are a lot of potential benefits.

- You build some time into your day to think systematically about what you are doing, instead of randomly trying things.
- You keep a record of key results, that will turn into plots or tables in a paper draft.
- You keep a record of the logic behind why you did something and the method you used, which can turn into text for a paper.
- Knowing what you did and why can help you plan what next steps you can take.
- In 6 months, when you don't remember the details of what you did, you can simply pull up your records and read about it.
- And others!

This is a very personal thing, so you have to use a system that works for you. The most important parts of your system are (a) that it is something you will actually use (don't set up a lot of elaborate systems if you won't use them), (b) it should at least capture the key results you want to remember at your next research meeting, as well as the problems you ran into that you couldn't solve or that you solved in a way you aren't sure is correct or optimal, (c) you are consistent and systematic, so you know where to look to find the notes from a given day or experiment.

At various stages, I have tried or known people who have tried some of these options:

- Maintain a wiki where you post daily updates.
- Start a research note about your project, and as you progress add text to explain what you are doing and why, and the key results. (Essentially a running paper draft, but much rougher).
- Start a set of powerpoint slides about your project, and as you progress add slides with key methods and results.
- Keep a handwritten lab notebook as if you were working in a lab.
- Use a system like OneNote to take and store your notes on a computer.
- Especially since you are in computer science, use git to version control your code and notes.

You can experiment with different formats. A common one is a "diary" style, where you record the time, experiment, and results as you go. Another one would be to have a regular slot in the day where you briefly write up the key accomplishments you made that day. (Keep in mind that "I tried this and it didn't work" is a valid accomplishment :) -- particularly if you understand and record the reason why it didn't work)

There's no right or wrong answer. I would recommend starting out with something simple that is easy to do and maintain, and then expand as you learn what you need and how you like to work.

Comment: I have to agree that a grad student sending me daily updates would be really annoying.

Comment: Keeping a daily log and sending it daily are different things, of course.

Comment: @Buffy Definitely agree. What I got from the OP's question and comment is that they want to use this report both to send to their advisor as "proof of work" and as a daily log, just trying to nudge them in the direction of the latter.